# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AndroidNotificationSound'

Tags: android, flutter, audio, localnotification, flutter-notification

this is the dart analyses info:

```
error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AndroidNotificationSound'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [mediminder] lib/src/ui/new_entry/new_entry.dart:335)
```

and the file "new_entry.dart" still te same original one from here:

```
Future _showNotificationWithSound() async {
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id', 'your channel name',
      sound: 'sneezenotification',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high);

  var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
     android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0,
    'New Post',
    'How to Show Notification in Flutter',
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: 'Custom_Sound',
  );
}
```

the error is in the line

sound: 'sneezenotification'.
Note: I already added sneeze notification.mp3 in android>app>res>raw

Answer (score 0):

```
sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('sneezenotification'),
```

Change like this and change "channel_id 3" its work for me

Comment: This could be the example that I'm seeking lately.  Maybe with the Raw-Resource call, it becomes unnecessary for the raw folder to be called, so that only the file's name need be called.  And I read somewhere that once a channel has been set, it cannot be edited - so, in order to add the sound, maybe the channel's name or iD or both must be changed.  If it works I'll be back to salute.

Comment: So, I tried your directions @Arafat, and the notification came through, as it had been, however there was no sound with the notification.  Just to confirm.  It probably means that the sound needs to be referenced in a different way.  Thank you for your response still as it does seem to help with a step closer.

Comment: The error message I received after some testing suggests that the file I have referred to was found, so, the fact that it isn't being played could mean that it isn't in the correct format.  The current format is .m4a.  Further research and I found an answer saying that the format should be mp3.